# marquee text on status bar in vb 6.0

Tags: vb6

I am developing new vb 6 application, I want to display a scrolling text (marquee) 
on a status bar like news Line text I already have two panels used and now in the 
third panel I want to use marquee.

I have done following but text is scrolling from middle of the panel it should be 
scrolled from the right end to left end continuously.

```
Dim i As Byte
dim txtSample As String

txtSample = " - - - MARQUEE TEXT - - - "
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    i = i + 1
    StatusBar1.Panels(3).Text = Mid(txtSample, i)   
    If i > Len(txtSample) Then i = 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is actually correct but you are actually reducing the content in a rapid manner makes it a marquee. So to make it start from far edge instead from the length of your string, you have to buffer your string with space to cover the whole panel visible area.. something like this should do

```
txtSample = Space(150) & "- - - MARQUEE TEXT - - - "
```

Comment: I have tried that but in my application txtSample is coming from database which is concatenation of multiple values. So length is variable, please suggest the way to maintain the uniformity.

Comment: @YogendraAslekar Even if the length of the Marquee Text varies, the  number of characters required to fill the marquee panel is fixed .. so if it is 350 characters max that can fill the total marquee panel space. To pad the text from database, `txtSample=Space(Abs(350-Len(StringFromDatabase))) & StringFromDatabase`